# Laravel api sanctum CSRF token mismatch in chorme

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-sanctum

I have vue app & backend laravel , for auth use SPA Authentication

Everything is fine in localhost but in server have some issue

I send login request to sanctum/csrf-cookie then /login and return 200 and logged but when redirect to dashboard get error :

```
CSRF token mismatch.
```

this issue only in google chorme but in firefox works fine

I have two sub domain :
app.mydomain.com and api.mydomain.com

```
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=app.mydoamin.com
SESSION_DOMAIN=.mydoamin.com
```

also in vue app :

```
window.axios.defaults.withCredentials = true
```

my cros settings:
'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie','login-user'],

```
'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

Comment: API routes don't load the session so don't know the correct CSRF token.

Answer (score 0):

What are your settings in config/sanctum.php? Set session_domain to .localhost in the .env file
This resolved similar issue for me.

Comment: in localhost works fine I mean in webserver not working

Comment: @lock laravel includes webserver in its framework. is php artisan serve working for you?